# Одновременно хочу вывести как самое большое число, так и самое маленькое. Не получается додуматься до того, что должно быть между stop и if a > g

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
x = 0
y = 1    
g = int(input('Точка отправления: '))    
z = g    
while x < y:
  x += 1
  y += 1
  a = int(input('Число: '))
  stop = int(input('Введите stop, если хотите остановиться: '))
  if a > g:
      g = a
  if a < z:
      z = g

print("Самое большое число:", g)
print("Самое маленькое число:", z)
```

Comment: Нужны отступы. Есть подозрение, что из `while` просто нет выхода. Да и `"stop"` к целочисленному типу привести не получится, даже не смотря на то, что переменная и не используется нигде. Подробнее распишите логику, а то не очень понятно, что происходит.

Comment: Совет: давайте переменным понятные названия. minimum, maximum и т.д. С таким именами, как у вас, уже через две строчки непонятно, где что.

Answer (score 1):

Выглядит так, что `x` и `y` вам и вовсе не нужны.
Если я правильно понял идею, вам может подойти что-то вроде

```
    n_max = int(input('Точка отправления: '))    
    n_min = n_max    
    while True:
        stop = int(input('Введите stop, если хотите остановиться: '))
        a = int(input('Число: '))
        if a > n_max:
            n_max = a
        if a < n_min:
            n_min = a

    print("Самое большое число:", n_max)
    print("Самое маленькое число:", n_min)
```

P.S. выход из цикла по `stop = int(input('Введите stop, если хотите остановиться: '))` я бы тоже поменял, но тут вопрос не об этом..

Насчёт вариантов, как выйти из цикла - можно, к примеру так:

```
    def read_number():
        try:
            return int(input('Введите число (либо нажмите Enter, чтоб прекратить): '))
        except ValueError:
            print("Приём чисел закончен :)")
            return None

    while True:
        a = read_number()
        if not a:
            break
        if a > n_max:
            n_max = a
        if a < n_min:
            n_min = a
```